# Raspberry PI GSM HAT connecting to network problem

Tags: raspberry-pi, serial-port, gsm, dial-up, pppd

I have a Raspberry PI with [this](https://www.waveshare.com/wiki/GSM/GPRS/GNSS_HAT) GSM hat, and I want to connect to the mobile network with it. I have tried a couple of combinations of the `gprs` file to achieve this, but none of them would work.

I tried to go trough the [provided instructions](https://www.waveshare.com/wiki/SIM868_PPP_Dail-up_Networking) on the wiki.
That resulted in an error:

```
Script /usr/sbin/chat -v -f /etc/chatscripts/gprs finished (pid 1569), status = 0x3
```

When I start the connection with this command: `pppd call gprs &`

I get this if I check the `/var/log/syslog` file:

```
pppd[991]: pppd 2.4.7 started by pi, uid 0
chat[994]: abort on (BUSY)
chat[994]: abort on (VOICE)
chat[994]: abort on (NO CARRIER)
chat[994]: abort on (NO DIALTONE)
chat[994]: abort on (NO DIAL TONE)
chat[994]: abort on (NO ANSWER)
chat[994]: abort on (DELAYED)
chat[994]: abort on (ERROR)
chat[994]: abort on (+CGATT: 0)
chat[994]: send (AT^M)
chat[994]: timeout set to 12 seconds
chat[994]: expect (OK)
chat[994]: alarm
chat[994]: Failed
pppd[991]: Script /usr/sbin/chat -v -f /etc/chatscripts/gprs finished (pid 993), status = 0x3
pppd[991]: Connect script failed
```

The `/etc/ppp/peers/gprs` file:

```
#!/bin/bash
user "myusername@realm"
connect "/usr/sbin/chat -v -f /etc/chatscripts/gprs"
#/dev/modem
/dev/ttyS0      
# Speed of the serial line.
115200
nocrtscts
debug
ipcp-accept-local
ipcp-accept-remote
# Assumes that your IP address is allocated dynamically by the ISP.
noipdefault
# Try to get the name server addresses from the ISP.
usepeerdns
# Use this connection as the default route.
defaultroute
# Makes pppd "dial again" when the connection is lost.
persist
# Do not ask the remote to authenticate.
noauth
```

Also I changed the pin in the `/etc/chatscripts/gprs` file:

```
# +CPIN provides the SIM card PIN
OK              "AT+CPIN=1234"
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting the **APN** of the service provider in the third line of the gprs file? The details come along when you purchase the SIM card.

It should be something like:

```
connect "/usr/sbin/chat -v -f /etc/chatscripts/gprs -T APN"
```

You may find an example in the following link:

https://www.rhydolabz.com/wiki/?p=16325